# django one template - many views - beginner

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have managed (with a lot of assistance) to create a basic test blog in django 1.4.6 and python 2.7.

I can display the blog entries as a list (main page) and then allow the user to view each individual blog entry by clicking on the blog entry link.

I am now attempting to display the blog entries by author and by archive (by the published date of the blog entry).

**Is it possible to have the *one blog page* that can list the blogs by date (most recent first), by author and by archive (by the date - most recent last)?**

I am assuming the code is written in the urls.py and views.py files with the output to the single blog page, but I haven't yet found an example to work from and I can't quite figure this out on my own.

Here is my models.py:

```
class BlogPostDetails(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    blog_post_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    blog_post_date_published = models.DateField()
    blog_post_author = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    blog_post_body = models.TextField()
    blog_post_allow_comments = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    blog_post_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    blog_post_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.blog_post_title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-blog_post_date_published']
        verbose_name = ('Blog')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Blogs')
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def blog_post_item(request, blog_posts_id):
    blog_posts  = BlogPostDetails.objects.get(pk=blog_posts_id)
    language_versions = get_language_versions(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'core/details/blog/blog_item.html', {
        'blog_posts': blog_posts,
        'display_default_language': display_default_language(request.user),
        'languages': LANGUAGES,
        'language_versions': language_versions,
        'language_versions_num': len(language_versions),
})

def blog_post_list(request):
    blog_posts = BlogPostDetails.objects.filter(blog_post_date_published__lt=datetime.today())
    language_versions = get_language_versions(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'core/details/blog/blog_list.html', {
        'blog_posts': blog_posts,
        'display_default_language': display_default_language(request.user),
        'languages': LANGUAGES,
        'language_versions': language_versions,
        'language_versions_num': len(language_versions),
})
```

Here is my urls.py

```
    url(r'^details/blog/blog_list/$', 'blog_post_list', name='blog_post_list'),
    url(r'^details/blog/blog_item/(?P<blog_posts_id>\d+)/$', 'blog_post_item', name='blog_post_item'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Some advices:

1. You shouldn't use model name prefix in model field names, as you see code look much better:

   ```
   class BlogPost(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       date_published = models.DateField()
       author = models.CharField(max_length=25)
       body = models.TextField()
       allow_comments = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
       timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.title

       class Meta:
           ordering = ['-date_published']
           verbose_name = ('Blog')
           verbose_name_plural = ('Blogs')
   ```
2. Update django up to 1.6
3. User [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)(filtering and ordering [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering))

**And yes - it is posible to use one template for you task**

You should pass order type as url parameter.

```
url(r'^details/blog/blog_list/(?P<order_type>\w+)/$', 'blog_post_list', name='blog_post_list'),


def blog_post_list(request, order_type='date_published'):
    blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(date_published__lt=datetime.today()).order_by(order_type)
    language_versions = get_language_versions(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'core/details/blog/blog_list.html', {
        'blog_posts': blog_posts,
        'display_default_language': display_default_language(request.user),
        'languages': LANGUAGES,
        'language_versions': language_versions,
        'language_versions_num': len(language_versions),
})
```

**If you want to use one url - the only way that i see is javascript on page ordering.**